# Как сделать движение обьекта с ускорением?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть пила, которая двигается туда-сюда с ускорением. На половине пути меняет ускорение на противоположное.

Проблема в том, что нет плавности и дергается. Та и когда пила доходит до половины пути, параметры далеко от нужных.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Или же, если вы предложите свою реализацию равномерно ускоренного движения, буду очень рад :) )

P.S Я новичок, не бейте палками :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SawAcceleration : Saw
{
    private double maxSpeed;
    private double startSpeed;
    private double acceleration;
    private double timeForMaxSpeed;
    private Vector2 halfDistance;  // когда пила прошла половину пути, сменить ускорение

    private double currentSpeed;
    private double currentTime;

    private bool insideTheMiddle = false; // когда пила заходит в эпсилон-окрестность центра пути

    private void Start()
    {
        start = transform.position;
        target = start + transform.right * distance * (goRight ? 1 : -1);
        halfDistance = (start + target) / 2;

        maxSpeed = speed;
        startSpeed = 0;
        acceleration = (maxSpeed * maxSpeed - startSpeed * startSpeed) / (2 * distance);
        timeForMaxSpeed = (maxSpeed - startSpeed) / acceleration;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if (currentTime >= timeForMaxSpeed)
            currentTime = 0;


        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position , halfDistance) <= 0.01 && !insideTheMiddle) // когда пила прошла половину пути
        {
            ChangeAcceleration(maxSpeed);
        }


        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, target) <= Mathf.Epsilon) // когда пила прошла весь путь
        {
            ChangeAcceleration(0);
            ChangeTarget();
        }


        currentSpeed = startSpeed + acceleration * currentTime;

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, (float)currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void ChangeAcceleration(double speed)
    {
        startSpeed = speed;
        acceleration = -acceleration;
        insideTheMiddle = !insideTheMiddle;
        currentTime = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Steering Behaviors в интернете полно статей на эту тему

Comment: Не писал бы сюда, если бы нашел нечто похожее в инете)

Comment: Мне кажется MoveTowards, это все-таки для равномерного вдижения. Для равноускоренного же больше подходит как рази таки Lerp (что значит `не нравятся`?). Там нужно указать стартовую позицию, окончательную позицию и параметр [0; 1] - нынешний прогресс между стартом и финишем. Этот параметр - перемещение, можно вычислить по формулам `S = (v+v0)/2*t` или `S = v0 + (at²)/2` или `S = (v² - v0²)/2a`. Потом его нужно нормализовать, чтобы оно принимало значения от 0 до 1, проще говоря разделить S на дистанцию между начальной позицией и конечной позицией.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему все-таки) Идею взял у автора выше. Но реализацию немного поменял

```
public class SawAcceleration : Saw
{
    /* 
    Взял за основу функцию f(x) = (1 - cos(a * x) ) / 2  , где a - параметр 
    В нашем случае скорость. Чем больше a, тем более "сплюснутая" функция, тем
    быстрее пила

    Область значения f = [0 , 1]
    Аргумент функции x - время
    Значение функции - пройденный путь пилы
    Период f = 2PI / a
    */

    private float time;
    private float lerp;
    private double period;

    private void Start()
    {
        start = transform.position; // point A
        target = start + transform.right * distance * (goRight ? 1 : -1); // point B
        period = 2 * Math.PI / speed;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        time += Time.deltaTime;

        if (time >= period)
            time = 0;

        lerp = (float)(1 - Math.Cos(speed * time)) / 2;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, target, lerp);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мой код писался прямо на сайте, я не проверял, скорее всего он плавный только в одну сторону и там была ошибка с обратным путём, но это пример, завтра перепишу. Периуд не равен делению радиан на скорость. А на % не обратил внимание, так как сделал ты, это косяк. /2f(f указатель, что это float), иначе получается int. double не нужен, это не астрофизика. Формулу я так понял, где то нашёл, sin, cos и pi (геометрию окружности) нужно учить и понимать, без них никуда.

Comment: Ну так никто и не говорит, что период это радиан на скорость) 

Период у cos(x)   2PI.
Период у  cos( a * x )  2PI / a.  (просто a в нашем случае a = скорость).  Функцию подобрал сам, ума много не нада)

Comment: Переписал......

Comment: У вас я взял идею. Идея отличная, гениальная и изящная. Но реализацию я немного не понял, поэтому сделал свою

Comment: Говорите... вы period(период) = 2*Math.PI(радианы)/speed(скорость). У меня в коде реальная скорость, если `_distance = 20`, а `_speed = 10`, пила дойдёт от `A` до `B` за две секунды.

Comment: Речь идет об периоде функции (1 - cos(ax) / 2 , а не про движение пилы

Answer (score 2):

Не проще использовать синусоиду?

```
public class Saw : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 2)] private float _startRate = 0f; // стартовая позиция (A>B>A-0>1>2)
    [SerializeField] private Transform _pointA; // пустой gameObject
    [SerializeField] private Transform _pointB; // пустой gameObject
    private Transform _transform;
    private float _distance;
    private float _way;

    private void Start () {
        _transform = transform; // кешируем трансформ, что бы не запрашивать заново
        if (_pointA != null && _pointB != null)
            _distance = Vector3.Distance(_pointA.position, _pointB.position);
        _way = _startRate*_distance;
    }

    private void Update () {
        if (_distance > 0) {
            _way += _speed*Time.deltaTime;
            // _distance*2f путь до B и обратно
            // % - остаток от деления
            _way %= _distance*2f;
            // нормализованное значение (A>B-0>1) (A>B>A-0>1>2)
            float WayRate = _way/_distance;

            // линейныое движение (A>B>A-0>1>0)
            /*if (WayRate > 1)
                WayRate = 1-(WayRate-1);*/
            // синусойдное движение
            WayRate = 0.5f-Mathf.Cos(WayRate*Mathf.PI)*0.5f;

            _transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_pointA.position, _pointB.position, WayRate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Выручили) Буду разбираться)

Comment: Ошибочка, в WayRate = 1-WayRate; забыл -1. Писал код прямо на сайте.